# how to convert dll.files into linux files

Tags: linux, linux-mint, dll

Installed Linux mint yesterday cause W7 does work anymore. Linux mint works OK. 
How can I convert my email history from emClient (dll-files) to linux-files.
I tried importing in Thunderbird, but thunderbird cant find emClient.
Need the history (send mails) for work.

Comment: It would be more important to know the actual program you've used under Windows before. Thunderbird as well?

Comment: First: dlls can not be (easily) converted to run on Linux. Second: No e-mail program saves *your data/e-mails* in dll files, and if it does, dump it and never look at it again because it is one of the most stupid programs out there. Third: There does not seem to be migration path for em client to Thunderbird. Fourth: You sure you used local (POP) e-mail management and not IMAP?

Comment: Stupid or not, I used emClient and all of my email history is there. Startup in windows mode does not work anymore. Therefor I went to linux mint. That works very nice. I can still get my personal documents etc. Only the email history is still captured in emClient. Tried to open it in Wine, but that doesnt work. It would be perfect if I got the mails as text-format. Thats why I wanna convert the dll-file with the mails into a file that can be read in linux mode. If someone has a better idea, please send it. Recovery of the mails is very important. Thx